# Defining multiple glob separately with PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to create a soundboard that supports both .ogg and .mp3 to accommodate multiple browser audio support.  One div needs to only display the .ogg files, and the other div should display .mp3 files.  But it ends up showing both file-types for both divs.

```
<?php
    $files1 = glob("audio/soundboard/*.ogg");
    $files2 = glob("audio/soundboard/*.mp3");
?>

<script>
$(function() {
    $("audio").removeAttr("controls").each(function(i, audioElement) {
    var audio = $(this);
    audio.closest('div').append($('<button>'+audio.attr("title")+'</button>').find('button').click(function() {
        audio[0].play();
    }));
  });
});
</script>

    <div id="ffchrome">
        <?php foreach($files1 as $file) { ?>
            <?php $title = str_replace(".ogg", "", str_replace("audio/soundboard/", "", $file)); ?>
            <audio src="<?php echo $file; ?>" title="<?php echo $title ?>"></audio>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>

    <div id="ie">
        <?php foreach($files2 as $file) { ?>
            <?php $title = str_replace(".mp3", "", str_replace("audio/soundboard/", "", $file)); ?>
            <audio src="<?php echo $file; ?>" title="<?php echo $title ?>"></audio>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this at the top of your document and remove all of the present javascript in your divs:

```
$(function() {
    $("audio").removeAttr("controls").each(function(i, audioElement) {
    var audio = $(this);
    audio.parent().append($('<button>'+audio.attr("title")+'</button>').click(function() {
       audio[0].play();
    }));
  });
});
```

Your mistake is running jquery's "each()" method several times for every audio on the page.

Also it might be a good idea to replace .click with .bind( but you need to reference documentation for that.

Comment: Okay I think I understand what you mean.  The .each() function is scanning the entire page for audio tags and then dumping the results into the designated div.  How would I get it to only pull from a certain selection, and not the entire page?  I noticed that you left the function intact in your example.

Thanks for your help by the way.  I'm stumbling through PHP, and not much makes sense to me at the moment.

Comment: No, i tweaked the function abit. It itetates thru all audio tags and only add buttons to divs that they are in. I also adjusted the way you find button with jquery.

Comment: I have your code implemented as shown.  I think something is still amiss, as nothing is being displayed in the divs.  Here is a link to see where I am testing it at.  http://www.thefs.net/soundboard/sb

Comment: I made a couple of small changes to the answer: your jquery version is quite old, so it does not support the `closest()` method, so i replaced it with `parent()` instead. One other thing was my mistake - no need for extra `find()` when the button was appended. Check it, it should work now.

Comment: That's it, you cracked it!  Thank you so much for getting this workable.  I was going to resort to iframes or conditional tags, all of which would have been cumbersome.  I really should use a newer version of jquery :/, but I didn't want to potentially break compatibility with other components of my site.